# How to get and set subtitle text dynamicaly in gstreamer C programming

Tags: c, events, gstreamer

I want to know if I can handle an event when a subtitle line is added to the video queue. This is my pipeline, and I've the same in C programming :

```
gst-launch filesrc location=./video.ogv ! oggdemux name=demux \
demux. ! queue ! decodebin ! subtitleoverlay name=overlay ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink \
demux. ! queue ! vorbisdec ! autoaudiosink \
filesrc location=./video.srt ! queue ! subparse ! overlay.
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could put a buffer [probe](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstPad.html#gst-pad-add-probe) on the queue's source pad that way:

```
gst_pad_add_probe (source, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, your_callback, NULL, NULL);
```

Your callback will be triggered each time queue gets something pulled from it. However I believe you'll be better off putting the probe on subparse's source pad, as you'll be sure to have your callback called when a subtitle line is pushed to be displayed, which is what I assume you really want :)

Comment: Yes that's it thank you. But this is no longer the order of the day, so maybe I'll try someday. I wanted to translate subtitle automaticaly !

Comment: The best thing in that case would be to write a "texttranslate" element that you would link after the subparse plugin I think.